# Custom Fonts in VIM

Tags: vim, fonts

I'm somewhat new to vim and wanted to add some custom fonts.

This is the one I wanted to add: https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans.

How would I tell vim to use this font since it's not part of the default font set.

Do I add this to the .vimrc?

I'm on Mac Catalina by the way.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using vim in the command line: Vim uses the font of your terminal emulator so if you set up your terminal emulator (iTerm2, Terminal.app etc) to use that font it should pick it up automatically.

If you want that font to be used exclusively in vim and you're using gvim you can change the `guifont` option which is documented on the [Vim FAQ](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-31.2):

"You can change the 'guifont' option to change the font used by GUI Vim.  To
display the current value of this option, you can use

```
:set guifont?
```

You can add the displayed font name to the .vimrc file to use the font
across Vim sessions. For example, add the following line to the .vimrc file
to use Andale Mono font.

```
set guifont=Andale_Mono:h10:cANSI
```

For Win32, GTK and Photon version of Vim, you can use the following command
to bringup a dialog which will help you in changing the guifont:

```
:set guifont=*
```

You can also use the -font Vim command line option to specify the font used
for normal text."

Comment: I understand that, thank you for your response. But how do I use custom fonts. I'm using GUI Vim and when I type the "Andale_Mono" line it doesn't show that font.

Comment: Ah, my apologies! It might be defined differently. See https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_gvim_font_in_MacOSX